# Strange behaviour with Part?

Tags: core-language

I just debugged a strange behaviour with Part. With the first example below the replacement of columns 2 and 3 is done line by line, as I would expect. It also works correctly when x has only one line.

```
x={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
x[[All,{2,3}]]={"a","b"}
x//TableForm
(*{{1, "a", "b"},
   {4, "a", "b"}, 
   {7, "a", "b"}}*)
```

But when there are only two lines the replacement is done column by column !!!
This is very strange as I shouldn't worry about the number of lines.

```
x={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
x[[All,{2,3}]]={"a","b"}
x//TableForm
(*{{1, "a", "a"}, 
   {4, "b", "b"}} *)
```

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Make sense, if there are two rows then each gets one element. Deeper threading done in the first example is a covinience I'd not count on and expect since it is not working automatically for lists either.

Comment: e.g. `{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} + {1, 2}` it does not work.

Comment: Or maybe "shallower level have higher precedence" is a good rule of thumb to remember.